# Grouped collection to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I need to achive array in format showed at the end, I'm using laravel collections

$query->get()->groupBy('COLOR')->toArray();

```
array:2 [
  "GREEN" => array:123 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "color" => "GREEN"
      "id" => "956"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "color" => "GREEN"
      "id" => "50"
    ]
...
```

Format I need to achive:

```
array:1 [
  "GREEN" => array:123 [
    0 => "956"
    1 => "50"
...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do all of this with the Collection class:

```
$query->get()->groupBy('COLOR')->map->pluck('id')->toArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to output an array, this would work, otherwise you can use push to add to a collection. Also no need to do `->toArray();`

```
$data = $query->groupBy('COLOR')->get();

$formatted_data = [];
foreach($data as $item) {
    $formatted_data[$item->platform][] = $item->id;
}
```

Output:

```
[
   "GREEN" => [
        0 => "956"
        1 => "50"
    ],
    ...
]
```

Comment: Not sure why you are grouping by colour there, you've not given me enough of the data to understand that

Answer (score 0):

You can right like this

```
$query->groupBy('COLOR')->pluck('id');
```

Comment: This will give OP a collection of ids, they want an array indexed by color